# Convergence of sequence with respect to Euclidean metric and square metric

Tags: general-topology, convergence-divergence, metric-spaces

I want to show that a sequence of points of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is convergent with respect to the Euclidean metric if and only if it is convergent with respect to the square metric.

My thoughts were the following. Assume a sequence $(x_n)_{n \geq1}$ converges with respect to the Euclidean metric, so
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\text{d}(x_n,x) = \sqrt{(x_n^1-x^1)^2 + \ ...\ + (x_n^n-x^n)^2}=0$$ Then it must be so that 
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\rho(x_n,x) = \max(|x_n^1-x^1|,\ ...\ ,|x_n^n-x^n|) = 0$$

and vice versa.
I'm just not sure how to prove this correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you have two steps ahead of you:

---

Step **1**:

Prove that if the sequence converges in Euclidean metric, it converges in the square metric:

- Assume that $x_n\to x$.
- Take any $\epsilon > 0$
- Find some $N$ such that if $n>N$, then $|x-x_n| < \epsilon$

**Hint**:

Write down what the fact

> $x_n$ converges to $x$ in the euclidean norm

tells you. And I mean write down **exactly** what it tells you, as in write down the definition.

**Hint 2**:

if $\sqrt{a_1^2 + a_2^2 + \cdots a_n^2} < M$, then can you prove that $a_i<M$ for all $i$?

---

Step **2**:

same basic steps, except that now you assume it converges in the square metric and prove it converges in the euclidean metric. This should be even easier.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that
\begin{equation}
\max_i |y^i - x^i| \le \sqrt{(y^1-x^1)^2 + \ ...\ + (y^n-x^n)^2} \le \sqrt{n} \max_i |y^i - x^i|
\end{equation}
implies $\rho(y,x) \le d(x,y) \le \sqrt{n} \rho(x,y)$. Thus, we have $d(x_n, x) \to 0$ iff $\rho(x_n, x) \to 0$.